# Share local account among two AD B2C tenants

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, passport-azure-ad

I've customers registered to an AD B2C tenant using a local account and I'l like to have them being able to login with those credentials on a different AD B2C tenant. Is it possible to somway federate the two AD B2C so that they can share the same user identity? 
I know that it is possible to create custom policy to let an AD B2C use a multi-tenant Azure AD as identity provider, but I think this is not the case if the user identity is stored a local account in the AD B2C itself. 'am I wrong ?

Comment: Hi @patrick. Are you using built-in flows or custom policies? In theory, you can add an OpenID Connect-based identity provider in one Azure AD B2C tenant that refers to another Azure AD B2C tenant, although I do seem to recall an issue with passing `state` from one to another.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, [Set up sign-in for multi-tenant Azure Active Directory using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-commonaad-custom?tabs=applications) also works in this case.

I assume that you have B2C tenant A and B. You are configuring custom policy for tenant A. You just need to access `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your B2C tenant B}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration` in the broswer and get the value of **issuer**. And then copy and paste the value into the **ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes** key of *TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml* file.

After completing the configuration in the link above, you could use local account from tenant B to log into the application of tenant A.

Comment: i still trying to have it working out but no luck. an you give me some hint about the App registration paragraph in the guide you referenced ? It says: "To enable sign-in for users from a specific Azure AD organization, you need to register an application within the organizational Azure AD tenant"; is it this application id that I have to use in each of the AAD B2C tenant for which I want local accounts to be shared ?

Comment: @patrick Yes. You should do the same thing for each B2C tenant.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this configuration.
In my test setup I've configured a Main-Tenant with Azure AD Connect and two additional tenants (A and B) with Azure AD B2C, both registered in the Main-Tenant, each with a different client secret.
In A I've created a SignUpSignIn user flow and running it I was able to register a new local account in the B2C directory
In B I've created a custom policy.
When I ask to login with the Tenant-A identity provider I'm prompted with a Microsoft login form that only accepts a corporate account, not the self-registered account on tenant A

Comment: Could it be related to the ClaimProvider I added to TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml file? It defines the item: `<Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>`, should it be changed to the discovery endopint of the first tenant ? Thanks for your time